# NoMethodError at '/json/order'

Tags: ruby, json, knockout.js, sinatra

I'm trying to post some JSON from knockout.js. I believe i'm getting the data from knockout appropriately as my POST in Console looks as such:

```
[{"quantity":1,"item":"Enchiladas"}]
```

My Response however looks like this:

```
<title>NoMethodError at &#x2F;json&#x2F;order</title>
```

I'm trying to parse the JSON into a ruby hash with the following code:

```
post '/json/order' do
  request.body.rewind
  @data = JSON.parse request.body.read
end
```

Comment: what about `post '/order.json' do

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I would try using a tool like postman (or curl) and trying to debug at the simplest level possible. A "NoMethodError" means Sinatra isn't routing your request properly, and probably has nothing to do with knockout.js...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I went a different route and am sending the JSON in a text field within the form I'm POSTing. Knockout is allowing me to populate the field and it sends with all the other information.